# finding the minimum element in a cyclic sorted array

Tags: c, algorithm

I have tried the following code to find out the minimum element in a cyclic sorted array. But it fails when the low = 1 and high =2 because the mid is always 1 and a[mid]=a[1] is always greater than the a[high].

I am trying to use Binary Search here to find the solution.

```
//finding the minim element in the cyclic sorted array
int arrC[]={10,13,1,3,4,5,8};
int low=0,high =6;
int mid=0,reset =1;
while (low < high)
{
    mid = (low+ high)/2;
    if (arrC[mid]>arrC[high])
    {
        low = mid;
    }
    else if (arrC[mid] < arrC[high])
    {
        high = mid;

    }
}
printf("minimum element is %d",arrC[mid+1]);
```

Comment: Do you mean a rotated array?

Comment: Yes @aaronman.It's a rotated sorted array.

Comment: You print `arrC[mid+1]` but your minimum mid is 0... your code will fail for the simplest case where the first element is the minimum, including when the array has a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal binary search, but if `arrC[high] < arrC[low]`, treat `arrC[high]` as infinity to account for the wrap around. To do that just change the line:

```
if (arrC[mid]>arrC[high])
```

To:

```
if (arrC[high] < arrC[low] || arrC[mid] > arrC[high])
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with your code

- As pointed by [Paulpro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/paulpro)...treat arrC[high] as infinity..
- Apart from that I would also suggest you to use

> `mid = low + (high-low)/2;`

Don't use `(low+high)/2` . This can cause the sum to exceed the limit of integer and will result in a negative value. One more reason your code can fail.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
//finding the minim element in the cyclic sorted array
    int arrC[]={10,13,1,3,4,5,8};
    int low=0, high = sizeof(arrC)/sizeof(*arrC)-1;
    int range;
    if(arrC[low]>=arrC[high]){
        while (range = (high - low)/2){// range = range / 2;
            if(arrC[high - range] <= arrC[high]){
                high -= range;
            } else {
                low = high - range;
                continue;
            }
            if(arrC[low] <= arrC[low + range]){
                low += range;
            } else {
                high = low + range;
            }
        }
        if(high == low + 1){
            low = high;
        }
    }
    printf("minimum element is %d",arrC[low]);//1
    return 0;
}
```

note: It is not possible to halve the search range simply when the same value is included in the ordered data if,  because it is not possible to easily determine the direction to be searched. But it is possible if the same value is not included.

Comment: random code without an explanation...I'm tempted to just downvote this..

Comment: downvoter If say random code, Show funny example of the operation.